# Remain until, before, for, to with nouns

Tags: prepositions, verbs, nouns

The common way to say that some time, events or whatever remains until the occurrence of something is (for instance):

- N days remain before Christmas
- N days remain until New Year
- N upgrades remain to reach level 4
- N seconds remain for new record

But when we want to say, that something (a noun/a thing) is ours after a certain amount of something, how do we say it without using a verb, which we consider being there in the context.

- N amount of money needed until/before the new computer can be bought.

Can we say?

- N amount of money until I buy a new computer.
- N amount of money before I buy a new computer.
- N amount of money to buy a new computer.
- N amount of money for a new computer.

Which would be correct?

Comment: Your first set of examples all include the verb ***remain***, but there's no corresponding verb in the second set. That in itself means none of your second set of examples are syntactically valid. Also, although it's valid to refer to, say, ***five days before Christmas***, you can't really refer to ***five dollars before new computer***. That would have to be extended to something like *[I need to save up another] five dollars **before I can buy** a new computer.*

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Yes, FumbleFingers, I do know that. The verb "remain" isn't the primary problem here, we can omit it as far as I know. "Ten minutes before we get there", "Five goals to victory", "Two clicks until the end of the game". See, we omit "remain(s)" here.

Comment: "Ten minutes before we get there" and similar *are not sentences* (they're ***noun phrases***), so your "we can omit it as far as I know" makes no sense. And I'm not even sure the text "five goals to victory" represents any kind of "grammar" at all. It's just some words grouped together that would probably "make sense" in the right context, but probably couldn't be easily included in a syntactically valid utterance.